# KSH Script to get the CPU usage

Tags: shell, unix, cpu, ksh, aix

Can somebody please help me to write a KSH Script to get the CPU usage of the AIX server  ?

Here I want my script to get the Current usage of CPU that time it is executed

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of tools on AIX (and elsewhere) to get the current CPU usage.

- nmon
  On AIX (and Linux) you have nmon. This gives very detailed infos on memory, cpu usage, disk usage, etc. It is normally used as an interactive tool.
- sar
  call `sar -u 1 1` to get the current cpu usage. See the manual page of sar for a whole lot of options. Depending on your installation you need to be root or add your user to the group "adm".
- Just call `w -u`. It outputs a little bit more than you ask for. If you don't need that you can use awk/sed/cut to cut it away.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following script in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), but I just tried it in [ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh) and it works all the same:

```
top -bn2 | grep 'Cpu(s)' | sed -n '2s/.*, *\([0-9.]*\)%* id.*/\1/p' | awk '{print "CPU: " 100 - $1" %"}
```

You can also use

```
top -bn1 | grep 'Cpu(s)' | sed -n 's/.*, *\([0-9.]*\)%* id.*/\1/p' | awk '{print "CPU: " 100 - $1" %"}'
```

for faster response, but the result will be less accurate.

Comment: Thanks pfnuesel. Did you try above command in AIX server. I am not getting output when run this command

Comment: No, I didn't and in fact I have no experience at all with AIX servers, but I guessed it should work on any [tag:ksh] terminal with [tag:top], [tag:grep], [tag:sed] and [tag:awk] installed. Can you try to rebuild the command step by step (i.e. first try `top -bn2`, then `top -bn2 | grep 'Cpu(s)'` and so on) and see where you have an output?

Comment: (krist [abcefd77] /ad/work: top -bn2
ksh: top:  not found                         )
                                                                           I am getting above error in AIX. Looks like this command is not available in AIX box which is being used by me